# JMeter- How to share groovy scripts among a number of isolated Test Plan

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I have a bunch of common groovy functions which I am reusing in different 'Test Plans'. I want to keep them in separate script files. I don't want to create jar. How can I import those files in JMeter JSR223 Assertion, Preprocessor and Postprocessor with minimum fuzz? These are more or less modular functions and I want to keep them separate for obvious reason.

I tried using "Script file" section of JSR223. But it seems that it is only for overriding the script.

How can I use an external groovy script file in JSR 223 assertion/preprocessor/post-processor?

Comment: You can save your functions as elements in jmx format and merge them into test plans when needed, is that a solution that will work with you?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a bunch of functions which you`d like to re-use in different jsr223 elements you can:

1. In your test-plan create one initial JSR223 preprocessor (or sampler) and define your functions:

```java
    def sum(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a + b
    }

    def isA(Integer x, Integer y) {
    }

    def isB(Integer x, Integer y) {
    }
```

2. Then using closure put them as objects:

```java
    vars.putObject('sum', this.&sum)
    vars.putObject('isA', this.&isA)
    vars.putObject('isB', this.&isB)
```

3. In any other JSR223 element in the script you can use those functions like that:

```java
    def sum= vars.getObject(‘sum’);
    println sum(2, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why `Script file` option doesn't work for you, you can save your Groovy code as separate files on the file system and reference them via "Script file" input.

Whatever.

You can make JSR223 Test Elements modular just like any other Test Element using:

- [Test Fragment](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments/)
- [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller)
- and [Include Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) combination

Answer (score 0):

You can define the Groovy functions in `{JMETER_HOME}/bin/utility.groovy` script file.

Optionally you can define the function in your own Groovy script and set the property `groovy.utilities=bin/utility.groovy` in `user.properties` file.

For example, add the following to the Groovy script

```
def getRandomRangeOption() {
    Random random = new Random()
    random.nextBoolean() ? "Between" : "Except"
}
```

You can call the function with

```
${__groovy(getRandomRangeOption())}
```

from anywhere in you JMX.